# Bearer token working on post man but null on browser

Tags: php, slim

```php
<?php

// ...

$app->get("/virgil-jwt", function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $header = $request->getHeader("Authorization");
    $token = explode("Bearer", $header[0]);
    $decode = JWT::decode(trim($token[1]), 'NTSCApp', array('HS256'));
    //var_dump($decode);
    //  print_r($token[1]);
    if (is_null($token[1])) {
        $res = ResponseResult::format(['error-message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    } else {
        $decoded_Array = (array)$decode;
        $decoded_Array2 = (array)$decoded_Array['data'];

        if (TokenHelper::isTokenExists(trim($token[1]))) {

            $get = new GenJWT();
            $jwt = $get->generate($decoded_Array2['id']);


            $responser = array("virgilToken" => $jwt);


        } else {
            // echo "invalid";
            $res = ResponseResult::format(['error-message' => 'Invalid Token'], 401);
        }
    }
    $status = getStatus(0);

    // var_export($response);

    return $res = $response->withJson($responser, 200);
    // return $res;
});
```

I get error on my browser while passing bearer as header to this code.

Am trying to get virgil token,  am not too good in english, please i need you guys help.

Comment: Please explain in your post what doesn't work in the browser but works in postman: What are you doing in postman? What are you trying to do in the browser that doesn't work?

Comment: when I pass bearer as Auth header in postman, it work's fine. but when I try using PHP-curl it returns null. the above code is what I use in receiving a response.